# Angular 4 how can i router to div?

Tags: angular, router

I have a component with 2 divs:

```
<div class='menu'>
 <menu-component></menu-component>
</div>
<div class='content'>
 <content-component></content-component>
</div>
```

The menu-component seems like this:

```
<a href=#>click to see some picture</a>
<a href=#>click to see another thing</a>
(etc...)
```

The content-component it's blank.

i want to click in the menu links and the content-component be replaced by another component like, as example, pictures-component. the same way we used to do with frames...

Comment: Can you explain your problem in a better way please?

Comment: You're basically asking how to use the router. There's documentation for that: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: yeah, I think this solves the case.